# css make element slanted and hoverable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this product card, which i am using for a model type card:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.common-card {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 -12px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.025);
    box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 -12px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.025);
}

.common-card h2 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.rooted-increment {
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.rooted-increment .cover {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fa9a91;
    background-image: url("https://i.mdel.net/oftheminute/images/2019/07/Jill-06.jpg");
    background-size: 120%;
    background-position: top;
    margin: -30px -30px 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rooted-increment .cover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: skewY(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="rooted-increment common-card">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <p>
        My name
    </p>
</aside>
```

I need it to be like this:

https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/video/upload/v1626393248/Screen_Recording_2021-07-15_at_7.47.07_PM_nlksby.mov

however, I cannot figure out 1) how to get the item slanted, and 2) to only do it on hover. I have been trying for days and cannot find anything on how to do this!! I tried using the `hover` css tag, but it didn't work, because i don't know how to mkae it appear and disapear on hover, and slanted is even worse :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example, you just need to move a skewed element on hovering `.rooted-increment`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.common-card {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 -12px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.025);
    box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25), 0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 -12px 36px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.025);
}

.common-card h2 {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.rooted-increment {
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.rooted-increment .cover {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fa9a91;
    background-image: url("https://i.mdel.net/oftheminute/images/2019/07/Jill-06.jpg");
    background-size: 120%;
    background-position: top;
    margin: -30px -30px 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rooted-increment .cover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff54;
    transform: skewY(25deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.rooted-increment:hover .cover:after {
    transform: skewY(25deg) translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<aside class="rooted-increment common-card">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <p>
        My name
    </p>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Do+Hyeon';
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clear-fix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card__collection {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Do Hyeon", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__collection .cards {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.card__collection .cards--one {
  backface-visiblility: hidden;
}
.card__collection .cards--one:hover:after {
  bottom: -20px;
}
.card__collection .cards--one:hover:before {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.card__collection .cards--one:hover .cards--one__rect {
  left: 45%;
}
.card__collection .cards--one:hover .cards--one__rect--back {
  left: 50%;
}
.card__collection .cards--one::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  background: #e660e3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  left: 0;
  right: -10px;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.card__collection .cards--one:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  bottom: -90px;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  right: -10px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.card__collection .cards--one__rect {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #0f9bc0;
  width: 126px;
  height: 55px;
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 60%;
  left: -45%;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 3.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.card__collection .cards--one__rect--back {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(34, 65, 154, 0.8);
  width: 126px;
  height: 55px;
  transform: skewY(7deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: -50%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.card__collection .cards--one__rect p {
  transform: skewY(-7deg);
  position: relative;
}
.card__collection .cards--two {
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card__collection .cards--two p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 83%;
  left: -100%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover p {
  left: 8%;
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover img {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover .cards--two__rect {
  top: 75%;
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover .cards--two__rect:before {
  transform: translateY(15px);
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover li {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover .cards--two__tri {
  right: -40%;
}
.card__collection .cards--two:hover .cards--two__tri:before {
  right: -312px;
}
.card__collection .cards--two img {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.card__collection .cards--two__tri {
  border-top: 220px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 190px solid transparent;
  border-right: 288px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__collection .cards--two__tri:before {
  border-top: 220px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 190px solid transparent;
  border-right: 288px solid #57ccfd;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: -220px;
  right: -612px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--two__rect {
  width: 750px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175%;
  left: -78%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card__collection .cards--two__rect:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f07306;
  transform: translateY(200px);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.card__collection .cards--two ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.card__collection .cards--two ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
.card__collection .cards--two ul li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--two ul li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.card__collection .cards--two ul li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-1 {
  left: 10%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-1 .shadow-1 {
  left: -20%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-2 {
  left: 60%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-2:before {
  left: -100%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-2:after {
  left: 80%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__rect-2 .shadow-2 {
  left: -10%;
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__circle {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__circle:before {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.card__collection .cards--three:hover .cards--three__list li {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-1 {
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 73%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-1 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  line-height: 6rem;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-1 .shadow-1 {
  background: #9b1308;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 1000%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  z-index: 8;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-2::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #57ccfd;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500%;
  top: 10%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-2::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #9b1308;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500%;
  top: 114%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__rect-2 .shadow-2 {
  background: #57ccfd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: 500%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__circle {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #9b1308;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__list {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 7px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(87, 204, 253, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
.card__collection .cards--three__list li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__list li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.card__collection .cards--three__list li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card__collection clear-fix">
  <div class="cards cards--two">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504703395950-b89145a5425b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d702cb99ca804bffcfa8820c46483264&auto=format&fit=crop&w=651&q=80" class="img-responsive" alt="Cards Image">
      <span class="cards--two__rect"></span>
      <span class="cards--two__tri"></span>
      <p>Lucy Grace</p>
      <ul class="cards__list">
        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cards cards--three">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480408144303-d874c5e12201?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=575213599ae24b3dbdfd84be79425c50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      <span class="cards--three__rect-1">
        <span class="shadow-1"></span>
        <p>Chris Levnon</p>
      </span>
      <span class="cards--three__rect-2">
        <span class="shadow-2"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="cards--three__circle"></span>
      <ul class="cards--three__list">
        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```